# How to copy an object from one bucket to another

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have been trying to copy an object from one bucket to another

for `e.g. bucket1/sample.jpg` to `bucket2/some_dynamic_folder/copied_sample.jpg`

here `some_dynamic_folder` is that , if it exists already it should copy the object under it , if not it should create and then copy

I have tried as below :

```
def copy_to_bucket(bucket_from_name, img_url, conventional_folder_name):
    try:
        file_name = img_url.split('/')[-1]  # to get name of image
        response = S3.copy_object(      # S3 has s3 client config
            Bucket= 'sample_bucket1' ,
            CopySource='/' + sample_bucket2 + '/' + file_name,
            Key= conventional_folder_name + '/' + file_name ,  # create a folder and copy there 
        )
        return response
    except Exception as error:
        return None
```

I have been getting the err as : `Boto3 copy_object "No Such Key".................`

Few of the images have spaces , read it might cause issue so replaced spaces using `urlparse` and  [here in the GIT hub issue mentioned this is not possible](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/996)

Any guiding links or any other workaround or an alternative to make this work is highly appreciated ... TIA

Comment: `Bucket` is for destiantion bucket, not source.

Comment: What is in `img_url`?

Comment: its `s3_path` for eg ... https://sample-buck.s3......jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CopySource` should not have a slash (`/`) at the front.

The format is: `bucket-name/path/object-name`

Also, the `Bucket` and `Key` are the **Destination**. The source bucket and key are provided in `CopySource`.

Comment: simply removing `'/'` would work ? or should i have to make any changes ? ... here the object name can be get from an s3 method ? so I am splitting the url

Comment: Try it, let us know if things are happier! The `CopySource` should contain the full path of the source object. If it doesn't work, use `print()` statements to show the contents of `CopySource` and `Key` to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Hey john same err ... and as you asked the print o/p is `{'Bucket': 'aiml-ies', 'CopySource': '8999123/1624255939855403200-0012e1ee-fde3-478f-ab27-18648feb2b05___FAM_L.Blight%201647_final_masked.jpg'}` .......... there is `%20` will this cause the issue ?

Comment: I have replaced spaces and it worked , but the thing is need to ensure there are no spaces on upload itself for avoiding the same issues

Comment: You might be able to use `import urllib` and then `img_url = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(img_url)`

Comment: but john could we add the same o/p of `img_url` to the `object-name`  here `bucket-name/path/object-name`?

Comment: If it works, sure! The thing is, where ever you are getting `img_url` from, it might be _urlencoded_ before it gets to your function, so the Lambda function needs to decode it.

Comment: I would give it a try john , my bad i could not get this though :( `Lambda function needs to decode it`